# Using the nonce and counter correctly for AES-CTR mode

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs, ctr-mode

I understand that in AES Counter mode I need to use a 128 bit nonce. The naïve way to do that would be to use a random 128 bit nonce, but I'm not sure the algorithm will be able to increment the counter correctly if it's passed as all random bits. I thought the correct way to do it is to use a 96 bit nonce and also a 32 bit counter starting at 0, for example:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('01ab23cd45ef67089a1b2c3d4e5f6a7b'); // 128 bits / 16 bytes
var nonce = '2301cd4ef785690a1b2c3dab'; // 96 bits / 12 bytes
var counter = '00000000'; // 32 bits / 4 bytes
var nonceAndCounter = nonce + counter;
    nonceAndCounter = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(nonceAndCounter);
var plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

var encryption = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, { iv: nonceAndCounter, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding });
var ciphertext = encryption.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

Is this the correct way to do it with the [CryptoJS library](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)? Or what is the correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question as I went digging into the library code to see what it really does.

***Summary:***

The answer is you can use either of two methods and it will work as expected:

**1)** Pass in a random nonce of 96 bits in length and the library itself will add the 32 bit counter automatically and increment it with every keystream block generated. E.g.

```
var nonce = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('2301cd4ef785690a1b2c3dab'); // 12 Bytes
var encryption = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, { iv: nonce, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding });
```

**2)** Pass in a random nonce of 96 bits in length and explicitly specify the 32 bit counter as well if you want to. You can even specify a counter like `00000009` if you want to start encrypting/decrypting from the 9th block. Below is an example starting from counter 0:

```
var nonce = '2301cd4ef785690a1b2c3dab';  // 12 Bytes
var counter = '00000000';                // 4 Bytes, start at counter 0
var nonceAndCounter = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(nonce + counter);  // 16 Bytes
var encryption = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, { iv: nonceAndCounter, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding });
```

***Explanation:***

Using the code in the question with 32 bit counter of `00000000`, the relevant code is in this file [mode-ctr.js](https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/src/mode-ctr.js):

```
/**
 * Counter block mode.
 */
CryptoJS.mode.CTR = (function () {
    var CTR = CryptoJS.lib.BlockCipherMode.extend();

    var Encryptor = CTR.Encryptor = CTR.extend({
        processBlock: function (words, offset) {
            // Shortcuts
            var cipher = this._cipher
            var blockSize = cipher.blockSize;
            var iv = this._iv;
            var counter = this._counter;

            // Generate keystream
            if (iv) {
                counter = this._counter = iv.slice(0);

                // Remove IV for subsequent blocks
                this._iv = undefined;
            }
            var keystream = counter.slice(0);
            cipher.encryptBlock(keystream, 0);

            // Increment counter
            counter[blockSize - 1] = (counter[blockSize - 1] + 1) | 0

            // Encrypt
            for (var i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
                words[offset + i] ^= keystream[i];
            }
        }
    });

    CTR.Decryptor = Encryptor;

    return CTR;
}());
```

When running this code in a browser JS debugger using a breakpoint, it converts the `nonceAndCounter` into a WordArray consisting of 32 bit elements:

`[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, 0]`

This is used to encrypt a block. To encrypt the next block it runs this line:

`counter[blockSize - 1] = (counter[blockSize - 1] + 1) | 0`

Which evaluates to take the `counter[3]` element i.e. the integer 0 and increments it to:

`[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, 1]`

With subsequent blocks and nonces I can see...

`[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, 2]`

`[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, 3]`

`[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, 4]`

And so on. So it appears to be working correctly this way.

Contrast this with how it works if you pass a 128 bit random nonce e.g.

`var nonceAndCounter = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('2301cd4ef785690a1b2c3dabdf99a9b3');`

This produces a nonce of:

`[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, -543577677, 0]`

So it creates 5 array elements!? Then the function increments the fourth element from `-543577677` to `-543577676`, then `-543577675`, then `-543577674` and so on. So it still works in a way, but but does not increment as nicely as starting from 0 and is perhaps more error prone.

When I passed in just a 96 bit random nonce, the library automatically added the start counter as 0 to the end of the counter array and incremented it correctly for subsequent blocks. e.g.

```
[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, 0]
[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, 1]
[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, 2]
```

Comment: So, it seems you don't need to set the counter explicitly because CryptoJS will automatically add it for you. It probably checks whether the last word is already 0. Also, CTR mode doesn't have an IV, it is called a nonce.

Comment: "Also, CTR mode doesn't have an IV, it is called a nonce." Noted, thanks. "So, it seems you don't need to set the counter explicitly because CryptoJS will automatically add it for you." Yes I tested this, just passing in a 96 bit nonce and it automatically adds the start counter as 0 to the end of the `counter` array e.g. `[587320654, -142251766, 455884203, 0]` and increments it correctly. Many thanks for the response Artjom. Sorry, I had tagged you because I saw your name attached to a number of the other CryptoJS answers and I figured you were knowledgeable on the library.

Comment: CTR mode doesn't have a nonce. One of NIST's examples for choosing an initial counter block does involve a nonce, though.