# nodejs crypto Is there any encrypt and decrypt text, should give different encryption at every time

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I know AES 256 CBC with buffer to give different encrypt but its length **66**.
here is my code

```
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  const ENCRYPTION_KEY = 'Must256bytes(32characters)secret';
  const IV_LENGTH = 16;
  function encrypt(text) {
    let iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH);
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', new Buffer(ENCRYPTION_KEY), iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text.toString());
    encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
    return iv.toString('hex') + 'XX' + encrypted.toString('hex');
  }
  function decrypt(text) {
    let textParts = text.split('XX');
    let iv = new Buffer(textParts.shift(), 'hex');
    let encryptedText = new Buffer(textParts.join('XX'), 'hex');
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', new Buffer(ENCRYPTION_KEY), iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
    try{
      decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
      return decrypted.toString();
    }catch(Err){
      return 'NULL';
    }
  }
```

Problem is encryption data length is **66** even for text is 1
So is there any encryption and decryption method should give different encryption data at every time with less than **10** characters for text is 1(according to my example)

*Thank you*

Comment: Must the result be printable string, or can you accept a Buffer as the result?

Comment: Also, is 10 a hard limit? This is easy to get down to 24 characters (or 17 bytes if you can accept a Buffer). 10 characters requires making security trade-offs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maarten covers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50307837/589259) most of the major points that I wanted to make, so this is just some elaboration and an example of it in Node.

The changes from your code are:

- Encode in Base64 rather than Hex. This is much more space-efficient. It would be even better to just use Buffers and not create a string at all; then we could have a 9-byte nonce rather than a 5-byte nonce.
- Get rid of separator character between the IV/nonce and the ciphertext. We know how long the IV/nonce is; we don't need a separator.
- Use CTR mode rather than CBC mode. This makes output length equal to input length.
- Use a nonce rather than an IV. Randomly choose the nonce from a 2^40 space. (Randomly choosing a CTR nonce is very dangerous in general. See below for why it *might* be acceptable in your use case; it is still never recommended.)
- Fix password generation by adding PBKDF2 (you could also just use randomBytes). Your password is highly insecure. It's an ASCII string, which means it represents a tiny fraction of the AES-256 keyspace. On the order of 0.000000000002% of the keyspace. That's how much less secure this is than AES-256.

As Maarten notes, it is quite dangerous for CTR mode to duplicate a Key+Nonce pair. If someone does that, they can learn the XOR of the two original messages. With that, they have a good chance of decrypting both messages. For example, if you duplicated your key+nonce on two messages and the attacker used that to discover that their XOR was 3 and knew that the encrypted text was a capital letter, they would know that the two messages had to be one of these:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('D', 'G'), ('E', 'F'), ('H', 'K'), ('I', 'J'), ('L', 'O'),
 ('M', 'N'), ('P', 'S'), ('Q', 'R'), ('T', 'W'), ('U', 'V')]
```

This kind of information is devastating for structured data like human language or computer protocols. It can very quickly be used to decrypt the whole message. Key+nonce reuse is how [WEP was broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Weak_security). (When you do this by hand, it's basically identical to solving a cryptogram puzzle you'd find in the newspaper.) It is less powerful the more random the encrypted data is, and the less context it provides.

With a random 5-byte nonce, there is a 50% likelihood of a collision after about 1.3M encryptions. With a random 8-byte nonce, there is a 50% likelihood of a collision after about 5.3B encryptions. sqrt(pi/2 * 2^bits)

In cryptographic terms, this is a completely broken. It may or may not be sufficient for your purposes. To do it correctly (which I do not do below), as Maarten notes, you should keep track of your counter and increment it for every encryption rather than using a random one. After 2^40 encryptions (~1T), you change your key.

Assuming that leaking information about two messages per million is acceptable, this is how you would implement that.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const ENCRYPTION_KEY = 'Must256bytes(32characters)secret';
const SALT = 'somethingrandom';
const IV_LENGTH = 16;

const NONCE_LENGTH = 5; // Gives us 8-character Base64 output. The higher this number, the better

function encrypt(key, text) {
  let nonce = crypto.randomBytes(NONCE_LENGTH);
  let iv = Buffer.alloc(IV_LENGTH)
  nonce.copy(iv)

  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', key, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text.toString());
  message = Buffer.concat([nonce, encrypted, cipher.final()]);
  return message.toString('base64')
}

function decrypt(key, text) {
  let message = Buffer.from(text, 'base64')
  let iv = Buffer.alloc(IV_LENGTH)
  message.copy(iv, 0, 0, NONCE_LENGTH)
  let encryptedText = message.slice(NONCE_LENGTH)
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', key, iv);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
  try{
    decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
    return decrypted.toString();
  }catch(Err){
    return 'NULL';
  }
}

// You could do this one time and record the result. Or you could just
// generate a random 32-byte key and record that. But you should never
// pass an ASCII string to the encryption function.
let key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(ENCRYPTION_KEY, SALT, 10000, 32, 'sha512')

let encrypted = encrypt(key, "X")
console.log(encrypted + " : " + encrypted.length)

let decrypted = decrypt(key, encrypted)
console.log(decrypted)
```

Comment: Had to correct my name; nobody writes my Dutch name correctly... Linked to your answer as well, Rob is easier to write :)

Comment: Sorry about that; my oldest is studying Dutch right now, and I keep learning that I always need to triple-check the spelling.

Comment: Thx @RobNapier. Cool :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can get a ciphertext of 5 bytes (or 10 hexadecimal characters) or less. But there are catches for such short ciphertexts.

Basically there are two ways. I'll start with the easier one.

### Counter mode (CTR)

You can use CTR (counter) mode with a nonce. Encrypting X bytes with CTR mode gives you exactly X bytes as a result. CTR mode does not require padding of the plaintext to N times the block size.

This nonce (number-used-once) *must* be a unique number, *or your plaintext is in direct danger of being exposed*. You cannot just rely on a random number; a 4 byte random number has a high probability of repetition because of the *birthday bound*.

So you either need to store the nonce separately or include a 4 byte nonce in your ciphertext. However, if you ever manage to reuse the nonce then you're screwed. For such a low amount of bytes that means that you basically have to keep a 4 byte counter, which means having to store *state*.

Generally CTR mode encryption routines require you to supply an IV rather than a nonce. This is simply the initial counter value. You *must* construct this value by getting the nonce, and then *right-padding* it with zero valued bytes until you get to 16 bytes, the block size of AES.

You can find sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29430375/589259), don't forget to upvote. Rob also has provided some sample code [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50308412/589259).

### Format preserving encryption (FPE)

With format preserving encryption the output of the encryption uses the exact number of bits or even values as the possible values of the input. That sounds great, but FPE consists of a bunch of relatively complex algorithms. Basically you'd have to find a crypto library in JavaScript to implement it.

Note that with FPE the same message will *always encrypt to the same ciphertext*. Depending on the application this may or may not be a problem.

---

Notes:

- You are using hexadecimal encoding, that's not the most dense encoding out there, you could use base 64 or even ASCII 85 encoding.
- It's more efficient to first concatenate the IV and ciphertext *as bytes* and then perform the encoding. If you have a static size for the IV you can simply use a constant rather than a separator.
- Your key should consist of random bytes, not a text string. Passwords need to be converted using password hashing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on my end, and the long sequence of hex characters seems perfectly normal to me.

Your ciphertext is always 66 characters long (in hex) because you're storing the 32 character IV, the 2 character delimiter ("AP"), and the 32 character (256 bit) ciphertext. Your code uses padding, and as such, the ciphertext will always be the next multiple of 16 bytes (32 hex characters) up from the length of the plaintext, and that's why you're getting such a long string of hex characters for a plaintext string that's only 1 character.

Unfortunately for you, padding is required for AES (at least in the mode you're using), otherwise it wouldn't function.

Comment: What do you mean padding

Comment: Padding basically adds bytes onto the end of the final block of the plaintext to get it to match the algorithm's block size (in the case of AES, 16 bytes). Without padding, the final block of plaintext wouldn't be handled in the same way as it would be with padding, and you wouldn't get such a long ciphertext for a 1 character plaintext string.

Comment: This isn't correct; AES cannot directly encrypt data that isn't the right length. If the data isn't a multiple of length 16, it must be padded or AES can't function. Ciphertext stealing and stream-like modes of operation (like CTR) can be used to avoid this, but the final length will still be much longer than 10 printable characters.

Comment: @RobNapier I found that out rather quickly. Thanks for pointing that out. @Gopalakrishnan You could add `cipher.setAutoPadding(false);` before you update the cipher, but then `cipher.final()` would throw an error unless your plaintext's length is a multiple of the block size. Padding seems to be required for AES. My apologies for the misleading answer.